# How to access images from tensorflow dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have created an image dataset in tensorflow, but now I want to use an image from the dataset as a variable (to view and manipulate it, etc) and I simply do not know how to access it, since batch datasets are not subscriptable, so I can't write

`image=dataset[0]`

I tried looking online but only found the `take` command, which seems to choose a random image every time which is not what I want. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

I tried to access an image from a tensorflow batch dataset, but my command didn't work so I'm looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I am not a TF/python expert but I recently had a similar problem which may help you as well. I had created a tf dataset which consisted of input and output images and I wanted to view them to be sure they were correct - in order to do this I needed to pull out images from the tf dataset structure which is basically what you need as well I believe? Although it's not clear to me if you need just one image or all of them, in any case I believe you can iterate over a tf dataset and extract the data portion as follows:

```
for img in my_dataset: 
    one_image = img.numpy()
```

In the event that your dataset is composed of images and labels then `img` will be a tuple of `(image, label)` so you must extract the image by simple indexing:

```
for img in my_dataset: 
    one_image = img[0].numpy()
```